# read.csv function unrecognised within an external script but works fine if I paste in to R console

Tags: r, csv

In a script that I want to run part of it imports a csv file. Ideally I would like to use read.csv. However I get the error `"Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "read.csv""`, when the script runs. However if I copy and paste the code in to the R console it works fine. Any ideas on how to get this to work in the script without intervention?
Code:

```
library(utils)
df <- data.frame()
df <- read.csv(Input_file, fill=TRUE, header=TRUE)
```

Thanks

Comment: Just a note: both of `library(utils)` and `df <- data.frame()` are redundant. Utils are loaded by default, and there is no need to initialize variables beforehand.

Comment: @user1 How are you calling the script?

Comment: Thanks, I initially hadn't declared them but as the code continued to not work I've been trying everything..

Comment: @user1 - where you are calling this script? Please provide data for that...

Comment: Yeah I've actually just realised that if I use 'source("Script1.r")' instead of 'sys.source("Script1.r")' (which is what I had been using) then the script runs fine. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sys.source()` by default will run the code in the `baseenv()` which happens to be an empty environment. Generally you should really only use 'source()' which uses your current environment.